# Drei Verben in einem Nebensatz

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb

Beim Lesen ist mir ein Satz aufgestoßen:

"Der Mann überlegt und fragt dann, ob er also später werde eintreten dürfen."

Ist es Altdeutsch oder gibt es eine feste Regel, die solche Fälle beschreibt? Liegt es daran, ob er im Futur ist, oder benutzt man immer diese Reihenfolge, wenn drei Verben in einem Nebensatz stehen?

Sind meine Beispiele dazu richtig?

1. Obwohl ich bleiben hätten können, bin ich weggegangen.
2. Nichts ist passiert, weil konnte nichts gemacht werden.
3. Es hat es hat, bloß weil er das wollte gemacht haben.

Comment: Was heißt der 3. Satz: "Es hat es hat"?

Answer (score 12):

**Warum 3 Verben:**

**Dürfen**, **Können** sind neben anderen [Modalverben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalverb), die in der Regel zusammen mit einem Verb verwendet werden:

> Ich darf eintreten.

**Werden** ist ein Hilfsverb zur Bildung des Futur. Daraus ergibt sich der Satz:

> Ich werde eintreten dürfen.

Ob es ein Nebensatz ist oder nicht ist hierbei egal, somit lassen sich "leicht" Sätze mit 3 Verben bilden.

**Die Satzstellung:**

Die Verben bilden alle zusammen den so genannten Prädikatsverband. Bei einem Nebensatz ohne Modalverb steht die finite (veränderliche) Verbform am Ende. Kommt ein Modalverb vor, so steht dieses am Ende. Zum weiteren Studium der Regeln kann ich folgende Lektüre empfehlen: 
[Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html)

Die Beispielsätze lauten richtig so:

1. Obwohl ich hätte bleiben können, bin ich weggegangen.
2. Nichts ist passiert, weil nichts gemacht werden konnte.
3. *Kann nicht korrigiert werden, da unverständlich.*

Comment: Die Antwort erklärt die Wortfolge nicht, was ja die Frage war

Comment: @Beta Danke für den Hinweis, habe es angepasst.

Comment: Der dritte Satz ist zwar am Anfang vergeigt, aber korrigiert wird er bestimmt mit "hatte machen wollen" enden müssen.